# Google Site Script to dynamically add posts from Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I have a Python cron job that pulls urls from sheet1 and populates sheet2 with scraped data from each url. Sheet 2 consists of [url, title, body, image urls]

I have an Old Google Site where I manually take sheet2's contents and create a new post. I want to automate this.

Structurally speaking would Google Scripts be able to pull and publish this dynamically? Lets say every time Sheet2 is updated (or a set interval).

I've worked with gscripts but never touched Google Sites before today.

Comment: Are you using the new Google Sites or the old Google Sites?

Comment: Old Google site

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is probably yes. Apps script can do this. You have a couple of options.

**Old Google sites**

**Option 1**

Embed an apps script into the site as an iframe and stream you posts in that.

**Option 2**

Use either a standalone apps script or one attached to the google site and update the site using the [Google Sites API.](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/)

**New Google sites**

Currently there is no apps script API for the new google sites. But you can embed JS HTML etc as a frame in the new sites. You can even use CDN libraries. Which means you can pull data from your sheet using something like AJAX.

**Custom built option**

The Google Sites API can be accessed anywhere you can handle Oauth. This means you can update Google Site from server-side code or from any client if you can handle Oauth.

Comment: Great info! Option 1 allowed for immediate implementation as we work on #2.